# Visualforce Error Message

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, error-messages

I am getting the following error message from my VF page and controller extension.  Does anyone know how to resolve?

**apex:inputField can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.**

***VF Page:***

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" tabStyle="Contact" sidebar="false" extensions="RDATasks" action="{!RDA}">

<apex:form >

<apex:sectionHeader title="Revenue Driving Activities"/>

<apex:actionRegion>
<apex:outputPanel id="taskList">
<apex:repeat value="{!listTask}" var="tsk">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Main RDA">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Account.Name}" label="Related To"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}" label="Name"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.Type_of_RDA__c}" style="width:35%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.Subject}" style="width:45%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.Type_Detail__c}" style="width:35%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.ActivityDate}" style="width:35%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.Status}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.Description}" style="width:100%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tsk.FollowUp__c}" style="width:100%">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="taskList,followTask"/>
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:outputPanel id="followtask">
<apex:variable var="tskF" value="{!listTaskFollow}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Follow-Up RDA" rendered="{!tsk.FollowUp__c}">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Account.Name}" label="Related To"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}" label="Name"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tskF.Type_of_RDA__c}" style="width:35%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tskF.Subject}" style="width:45%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tskF.Type_Detail__c}" style="width:35%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tskF.ActivityDate}" style="width:35%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!tskF.Status}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!tskF.Description}" style="width:100%"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>

</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>

    <apex:commandButton value="Add Another RDA" action="{!RDA}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Remove Last RDA" action="{!removeRDA}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save RDAs" action="{!saveTask}"/>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

***Controller:***

```
public with sharing class RDATasks{

    public list<Task> listTask{get;set;}
    public list<Task> listTaskFollow{get;set;}
    public integer n;

    Set<Task>Tasks = new Set<Task>();
    Set<Task>FollowTasks = new Set<Task>();

    private final Contact con;
    public RDATasks(ApexPages.StandardController myController){
        listTask = new List<Task>();
        listTaskFollow = new List<Task>();
        con=(Contact)myController.getRecord();
    }

//  Adds RDA Task to list
    public void RDA()
    {
        listTask.add(new Task(
           WhoId = con.Id,
           Status = 'Completed',
           ActivityDate = system.TODAY(),
           Subject = '',
           Description = '',
           OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
           WhatId = con.AccountId,
           RDA__c = TRUE,
           FollowUp__c = FALSE)
           );
    }

//  Adds RDA Follow-Up Task to list
    public void RDAfollow()
    {
        n=listTask.size() - 1;
        listTask[n].FollowUp__c = FALSE;
        listTaskFollow.add(new Task(
           WhoId = con.Id,
           Status = 'In Progress',
           ActivityDate = system.TODAY()+7,
           Subject = 'Follow-Up: '+listTask[n].Subject,
           OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
           WhatId = con.AccountId,
           RDA__c = TRUE,
           FollowUp__c = TRUE)
           );
    }

//  Saves list of RDA Tasks added
    public PageReference saveTask(){
        insert listTask;
        insert listTaskFollow;

        if(!listTaskFollow.isEmpty()){
            Tasks.addAll(listTask);
            FollowTasks.addAll(listTaskFollow);
        if(!Tasks.containsAll(FollowTasks)){
            integer last = listTaskFollow.size();
            listTask.add(listTaskFollow[last]);
        }
        }
        RDAfollow();
            {
            PageReference contactPage = new PageReference('/' + con.Id);
            contactPage.setRedirect(true);
            return contactPage;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since apex:inputField can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

So, probably this line onward you will receive the error.

Change `<apex:inputField value="{!tsk.Type_of_RDA__c}" style="width:35%"/>` to `<apex:inputText value="{!tsk.Type_of_RDA__c}" style="width:35%"/>`

And any `<apex:outputField/>` to `<apex:outputText/>`

You can try to explore the `<apex:column>` in this situation.

Comment: Thanks.  One problem is those fields are picklists.  Is there a way to keep that functionality?

Comment: do not use picklist as inputField

Comment: can you please close this question, if you are happy with the answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the tag to inputtext.

Comment: Can you provide a better answer, by being more specific? Check out [answer] for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that this is the culprit here:

`<apex:variable var="tskF" value="{!listTaskFollow}"/>`

You are then using the `tskF` variable in your code as though it is a `Task` object, when in reality it is a `List<Task>`, and an empty one at that. You will need to come up with a way of passing in a `Task` object from your controller to be used here instead.

As an aside, I would look at how you are populating the first value for `listTask` - currently, you are doing so by calling the `RDA()` method in the `action` attribute of the `apex:page` tag.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) for the `apex:page` tag contains the following warning for the `action` attribute:

> **Important**: This action should not be used for initialization or DML.

A better location for this call is in the constructor of your controller, as this is guaranteed to be called first on each page load. For more information see [Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Get Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm)

Comment: Does anybody know why page actions are recommended to not be used for initialization or DML? It's a common requirement to do a DML op on page load, and that's the workaround I've been using for years!